# Vertices connect to mirrored vertices

Tags: vertices

Im in edit mode with mirror and the vertices when i try to connect them are connecting to the mirrored [image: This is a picture of the vertices connecting to the mirrored accross the model in the middle]vertices. I found out what it was. The model had somehow flipped which side was which and i had to delete that section

Comment: You have to delete the section, it flipped the sides

Comment: [How to take a ScreenShot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/windows.html)